# Solidity, Member "transfer" not found or not visible after argument-dependent

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

Using Solidity ^0.5.0, 
I'm actually trying to implement an old code working in ^0.4.17, but it throws an error on Remix.
I checked syntax and everything but just can't catch what's wrong.
Any help highly appreciated.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Lottery{
  address public manager;
  address[] public players;

  constructor() public {
      manager = msg.sender;
  }

   function participate() public payable {
       require(msg.value > .01 ether);
       players.push(msg.sender);
  }

   function pseudoRandom() private view returns(uint){
    return uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.difficulty, now, players)));
  }

  function pickWinner() public {
    uint index = pseudoRandom() % players.length;
    players[index].transfer(address(this).balance);
  }
}
```

Here is the error message:

browser/Lottery.sol:22:8: TypeError: Member "transfer" not found or not visible after argument-dependent 
lookup in address.

players[index].transfer(address(msg.sender).balance);

^---------------------^

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please see [Solidity v0.5.0 Breaking Changes](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.0/050-breaking-changes.html).

As pointed out [here](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/050-breaking-changes.html?highlight=payable#explicitness-requirements):

> The address type was split into address and address payable, where only address payable provides the transfer function.

See my answer [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/63128/44078) for more details.

Change this line:

```
address[] public players;
```

To this:

```
address payable[] public players;
```

**EDIT**

Thanks smarx!

Comment: This answer was accepted, but I don't think it's the actual issue in the above code. `players[index]` was already an `address`, so casting it doesn't do anything. I believe the actual issue is that the type is `address` rather than `address payable`. The fix would be to use `address payable[] public players`.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the payable modifier on the initial declaration. 
Change

> address[] public players;

to

> address payable[] public players;

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood from your contract's business logic, all addresses enter the lottery wouldn't win a price, so you don't need to make all addresses payable.
Better way is making only the winner address payable by casting address type to a payable address as below.

```
    address payable winnerAddress = payable(players[index]);
    winnerAddress.transfer(address(this).balance);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how overall contract code looks like

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

contract Lottery {
    address public manager;
    address payable[] public players;
    
    constructor() { }

    function lottery() public {
        manager = msg.sender;
    }

    function enter() public payable {
        require(msg.value > .01 ether);
        players.push(payable(msg.sender));
    }

    function random() public view returns (uint8) {
        return uint8(uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.timestamp, block.difficulty, players)))%251);
    }

    function pickWinner() public {
        uint index = random() % players.length;
        players[index].transfer(address(this).balance);
    }
}
```